# Invoke interrupt from R code

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a generic function to catch all exceptions included in my package [`logR::tryCatch2`](https://github.com/jangorecki/logR/blob/804b6177e70043c92c83dc8840de391d9a107b76/R/logR.R#L21)  defined as:

```
tryCatch2 <- function(expr){
    V=E=W=M=I=NULL
    e.handler = function(e){
        E <<- e
        NULL
    }
    w.handler = function(w){
        W <<- c(W, list(w))
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
    m.handler = function(m){
        attributes(m$call) <- NULL
        M <<- c(M, list(m))
    }
    i.handler = function(i){
        I <<- i
        NULL
    }
    V = suppressMessages(withCallingHandlers(
        tryCatch(expr, error = e.handler, interrupt = i.handler),
        warning = w.handler,
        message = m.handler
    ))
    list(value=V, error=E, warning=W, message=M, interrupt=I)
}
```

As you can see in the last line it returns a list which is more or less self describing.
It makes the real reaction to the exceptions delayed after the `tryCatch2` call by simple `!is.null`:

```
f = function(){ warning("warn1"); warning("warn2"); stop("err") }
r = tryCatch2(f())
if(!is.null(r$error)) cat("Error detected\n")
# Error detected
if(!is.null(r$warning)) cat("Warning detected, count", length(r$warning), "\n")
# Warning detected, count 2
```

It works as expected, I can react with my own code. But in some cases I would like to not stop the *interrupt* process which is caught too. At the moment it seems I would need to add additional parameter to `tryCatch2` which would control if interrupts should be catch or not. So the question asks about some `invokeInterrupt` function which I could use in the following way:

```
g = function(){ Sys.sleep(60); f() }
r = tryCatch2(g())
# interrupt by pressing ctrl+c / stop while function is running!
if(!is.null(r$interrupt)) cat("HERE I would like to invoke interrupt\n")
# HERE I would like to invoke interrupt
```

I think if R is able to catch one it should be also able to invoke one.
How can I achieve `invokeInterrupt` functionality?

Comment: Why not change the interface? Instead of `if (! is.null(r$interrupt))`, provide a function so that the user has to do `if (r$has_interrupt())`, and you can invoke the interrupt in that function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph to do this I still need to know how to invoke interrupt from R code, right?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question then. I’m actually not aware of a way in R to do that, and if I understand some documents correctly it may not be possible at all.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have a different use case but the same problem: Unit testing of (simulated) user interrupts. Currently I guess I could call `signalCondition` with a self-made class of type `condition` and `interrupt` but I didn't try it so far (still browsing through SO for answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer but I have found that `rlang::interrupt` can throw "user interrupts":

> interrupt() allows R code to simulate a user interrupt of the kind that is signalled with Ctrl-C.
>   It is currently not possible to create custom interrupt condition objects.

Source: `?rlang::interrupt`

Internally it calls the R API function `Rf_onintr` which is an alias for the function [`onintr`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2cdea4811caa2417e2cf32a0c7ad3be70325eec1/src/main/errors.c#L189).

Basically an `interrupt` is "just" a special condition with these classes:
`interrupt` and `condition` (see the [R source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2cdea4811caa2417e2cf32a0c7ad3be70325eec1/src/main/errors.c#L1857)).

If you just want to simulate an interrupt to test `tryCatch`ing (without the need to interrupt a running R statement) it suffice to throw a condition with these classes via `signalCondition`:

```
interrupt_condition <- function() {
  structure(list(), class = c("interrupt", "condition"))
}

tryCatch(signalCondition(interrupt_condition()),
                         interrupt = function(x) print("interrupt detected"))
# [1] "interrupt detected"
```

Answer (score 4):

I can propose a partial solution, which relies on the `tools` package.

```
invokeInterrupt <- function() {
  require(tools)
  processId <- Sys.getpid() 
  pskill(processId, SIGINT)
}
```

However, be aware that throwing the interrupt signal (`SIGINT`) with `pskill` doesn't appear to be very robust. I ran a few tests by sending the exception and catching it with your function, like so:

```
will_interrupt <- function() {
    Sys.sleep(3)
    invokeInterrupt()
    Sys.sleep(3)
}

r = tryCatch2(will_interrupt())
```

On linux, this worked well when executed from the R commandline. On windows, the R commandline and R Gui did close when executing this code. There is worse: on both linux and windows, this code crashed Rstudio instantly...

So, if your code is to be executed from the R commandline on Linux, this solution should be OK. Otherwise you might be out of luck...

Comment: Nice trick. It won't work in my case, I want to invoke *interrupt* from the low level function but later be able to catch it a few frames higher in the call stack using another `tryCatch2` call.

Comment: I didn't spot `SIGINT` before (I didn't know signal exists) . I've tested it and it seems to not catch the upper interrupt correctly. Half of the bounty seems to be fair. I wonder why in-R interrupt is different from `SIGINT` signal, and if it shouldn't be the same?

Comment: I would love to see a better solution than the one I posted (which is really specific as it works only with linux), so yes don't accept this solution and let's wait to see if someone can crack this problem :)